# Find the duplicates with a twist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table called MyTable with the fields Id(int),Name(nvarchar),Value1(bit),Value2(bit)
EX:

```
1   Nathan  True    False
2   Nathan  True    False
3   John    True    False
4   John    False   True
```

So i can easily find the duplicates by name like this:

```
select 'First_Id'=a.Id,'First_Value1'=a.Value1,'First_Value2'=a.Value2, 
        'Second_Id'=b.Id,'Second_Value1'=b.Value1,'Second_Value2'=b.Value2
        from MyTable a, MyTable b where a.Id>b.Id
        and a.Name = b.Name
```

and then i can delete the ones with with the Id in the SecondId...

What i want to do is find the duplicates and do a logical OR between all the Value1 of the duplicate group and update every single record from the duplicates with that value and then the same thing for value2.

EX:

For the example above there will be 2 groups of duplicates

and the result will be:

```
1 Nathan True False
2 Nathan True False
3 John   True True
4 John   True True
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to update `Value1` and `Value2` for each group so that they are the same as the first row in that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
update a set a.Value1=b.new_value1  ,a.Value2=b.new_value2

from MyTable a
inner join 
(select Name,cast(SUM(cast(Value1 as int))as bit) new_value1,
cast(SUM(cast(Value2 as int)) as bit) new_value2 from MyTable
group by Name) b

on a.Name=b.Name;

select * from MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37e00/9)

**Explanation :** `cast(Value1 as int)` is required as `SUM` will not work on `bit`. And then `cast(SUM(cast(Value1 as int))as bit)` converts any non-zero value to 1(true).

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)

Comment: Yes... that is exactly what i needed... I dont understand though what does this casting from int to bit do... every number larger than 0 is seen as 1 (true) when cast ... why ?

Comment: no...i dont want to remove it.. it does its job.. it's just that i dont understand how that works..

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions about your question and produced a [SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37e00/1)

The assumption I made is that you will only have a maximum group count of two, that is, each name is only duplicated, at most, once. If this is correct, here's what you can do. You use bitwise functions in SQL Server to "OR" values together. So the query to update each row for each name with the ORed values could be:

```
;with upd_val_cte as 
 (select a.Name, (a.Value1 | b.Value1) as Value1,
 (a.Value2 | b.Value2) as Value2
from MyTable a
join MyTable b
on a.Name=b.Name
and a.id<b.id)

update MyTable 
set Value1=d.Value1,
    Value2=d.Value2 
from upd_val_cte d
where MyTable.Name=d.Name
```

In order to see the results with the words "true" or "false" as you have shown, you can use the following select statement.

```
select id, Name, case when Value1=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as Value1,
                case when Value2=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as Value2
from MyTable
```

In SQL Server, the value of 0 in the bit column represents false and 1 is true, so, you may want to use these directly.

If you can have more than one tuple with the same Name value, let me know...By the way, could you tell us why you want to do this?

Here's a reference for doing Bitwise operations in SQL Server 2008.

[MSDN article on Bitwise operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: your query looks good but it will not give the correct answer if i add one more Nathan 0 1..